# View changes of files in a specified duration

Tags: git

Suppose I have a git repo named `dev` containing these files:

- tony_homework.md
- mary_homework.md
- hery_homework.md

Files are updated on a daily basis and pulled request to me by the three students, like:

```
git add tony_homework.md
git commit -m 'update tony_homework.md 2018-03-08'
...
git add mary_homework.md
git commit -m 'updated mary_homework.md 2018-03-08'
...
git add hery_homework.md
git commit -m 'updated hery_homework.md 2018-03-08'
...
```

I merge the PRs then need to combine the newly added contents of the three files to a new '2018-03-08.md' file.

Now, I manually copy the added from each file and paste them to '2018-03-08.md'.

How to solve the problem in a smart way?

Comment: What should `2018-03-08.md` exactly contain? (the diff? the joined content of the three files?) Could you add an example?

Comment: Yes, the diff, the jointed content of the three files. @XavierGuihot

Comment: Would a solution with shell commands be possible? I assume there are other students file in the same folder which might not be updated and thus not be pushed to the daily file?